# Quickly make file on Linux server available to Windows client

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

I have a remote Linux server which I am SSH'd into using PuTTY from my Windows client.  Within the shell, I create some file, and I wish to quickly make it available to the Windows client.

Currently to do so, I go the the client, open FileZilla, browse to the file location, and download it.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: @terdon. Why would this be any better than Filezilla?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried it since I don't use Windows but I thought you might be able to set up your windows box as an scp server in which case you could run `scp file user@windows.box:/path/to/file` from the server's command line to transfer the file to your windows box. This may well not be possible with winscp which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @terdon.  Interesting.  I think you are one to something. Similarly, I am wondering if I can use DropBox as a middle man?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make a [Samba Share](http://www.samba.org/)? It could be useful.

Comment: How would you suggest this working with a "remote Linux server"...?  Unless they have a VPN or something of the sort, I am not sure I see it.

Comment: Thanks Krishath,  How would you recommend using Samba Share for this purpose?

Comment: If you have root access to it, install SMBD (SambaDaemon) and configure it to share the folder you need. In this way, for example, you can create a folder where you'll put all the files that we'll be readily readable by a Windows user. After having done that you could access it by mounting it remotely by opening the SMBD port on your router.